# .putty/randomseed in home folder

Tags: mac, finder, ssh

I have recently found out that there is a hidden folder in my Home Directory named putty with a file named "randomseed" inside. I know PuTTY on Unix stores its data there, and I have read around that FileZilla might actually create that folder. Problem is, I have never used PuTTY and can't remember installing FileZilla on my MacBook Pro. I have looked at the date the folder/file were last opened, and it was months ago so it was impossible for me to find out whether it coincided with installing any apps.

For good measure I have deleted the folder and the file within it. I have even downloaded and opened FileZilla just to see whether that folder was going to be regenerated but no.

I am aware that finding out where it came from is going to be impossible, but I'm looking for reassurance that it might not be anything malicious, like someone trying to connect to my machine via SSH or something, (all the Sharing options in my System Preference are disabled).

If anyone has any idea about this please let me know, I am a bit worried.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you use any other 3rd party FTP client or remote file management app?

Answer (score 1):

This file is generally created by FileZilla on macOS. However, that’s not the only app to do so.

Check if you have any other FTP client app or remote file management app. A while ago, on one of our development Macs, I found this file to be created when the only non-bundled app that we installed was Xcode. The last modified time of the file used to change every time Xcode was launched.

It is advisable to delete the file from your Home directory and keep watching the location for any signs of it coming back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was aware of FileZilla, but I don't recall installing it. I haven't seen Xcode actually touching the file as far as I could tell, and certainly it hasn't re-created it since I deleted it. The only other non bundled apps I could think of are Cyberduck, Postman that could be making use of that file. What's weird is that Unix machines have ssh built-in so why would any software need to use that putty folder? What concerns me is whether that might have come from a malicious attack and ppl were trying to connect to my machine?

Comment: Cyberduck appears to be the likely culprit.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had thought about it. I did check another laptop where I have Cyberduck installed and that file is not there though.